# How to write parallel code with Haskell vectors?

Tags: haskell, vector, parallel-processing

One one hand, in Haskell [`Vector a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html) seems to be the preferred type to use as an array of numbers. There is even an (incomplete) [Vector Tutorial](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial).

On the other hand, [`Control.Parallel.Strategies`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel/3.1.0.1/doc/html/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html) are defined mostly in terms of `Traversable`. Vector library doesn't provide these instances.

The minimal complete definition of `Traversable t` should also define `Foldable` and

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

I don't see how `sequenceA` can be defined for `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector`. So, what is the best approach to writing parallel code with unboxed vectors? Defining some new ad hoc strategies like `evalVector` or using `par` and `pseq` explicitly or using plain `Data.Array` instead of vectors?

P.S. Plain `Array`s are parallelizable without problems: https://gist.github.com/701888

Comment: Getting a little anxious for DPH to show some fruit, are you?

Comment: Well, sort of. I'd like to try writing numeric code in Haskell, and don't understand yet what I should use for that.

Comment: I don't think your version of parVector would work: `rseq` wouldn't evaluate any of the elements (its only WHNF) and the `V.concat` is an unnecessary O(n) operation - we're trying to force the computation of the elements, no need to construct a new vector.

Comment: also `vLen - half` should probably be `vLen - 1`, but that isn't quite right either as it segfaults for me.

Comment: My `parVector` didn't work indeed. `vLen - half` was correct.

Comment: FYI, I've e-mailed Roman with a variation on `parVector` hoping he'll include it in the Vector package.

Comment: I uploaded this as the package [vector-strategies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-strategies) as it seemed useful enough to a wide audience but Roman wasn't willing to add to the Vector build-deps (understandable).

Comment: Thank you, Tom. The package installs with both GHC 6.12 and 7.0 without problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a hack job for `parVector` but this worked for me:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.Parallel
import Control.DeepSeq

ack :: Int -> Int -> Int
ack 0 n = n+1
ack m 0 = ack (m-1) 1
ack m n = ack (m-1) (ack m (n-1))

main = do
  let vec = V.enumFromN 1 1000
  let res = (V.map (ack 2) vec) `using` parVector
  print res

parVector :: NFData a => Strategy (V.Vector a)
parVector vec = eval vec `seq` Done vec
  where
  chunkSize = 1
  eval v
    | vLen == 0 = ()
    | vLen <= chunkSize = rnf (v V.! 0) -- FIX this to handle chunks > 1
    | otherwise = eval (V.take half v) `par` eval (V.drop half v)
    where vLen = V.length v
          half = vLen `div` 2
```

And running this code:

```
[tommd@Mavlo Test]$ ghc --make -O2 -threaded t.hs
... dumb warning ...
[tommd@Mavlo Test]$ time ./t +RTS -N1 >/dev/null
real    0m1.962s user    0m1.951s sys     0m0.009s
[tommd@Mavlo Test]$ time ./t +RTS -N2 >/dev/null
real    0m1.119s user    0m2.221s sys 0m0.005s
```

When I run the code with `Integer` instead of `Int` in the type signature:

```
[tommd@Mavlo Test]$ time ./t +RTS -N2 >/dev/null

real    0m4.754s
user    0m9.435s
sys     0m0.028s
[tommd@Mavlo Test]$ time ./t +RTS -N1 >/dev/null

real    0m9.008s
user    0m8.952s
sys     0m0.029s
```

Rock!

EDIT: And a solution that is a bit closer to your earlier attempt is cleaner (it doesn't use functions from three separate modules) and works great:

```
parVector :: NFData a => Strategy (V.Vector a)
parVector vec =
  let vLen = V.length vec
      half = vLen `div` 2
      minChunk = 10
  in  if vLen > minChunk
      then do
        let v1 = V.unsafeSlice 0 half vec
            v2 = V.unsafeSlice half (vLen - half) vec
        parVector v1
        parVector v2
        return vec
      else
        evalChunk (vLen-1) >>
        return vec
  where
  evalChunk 0 = rpar (rdeepseq (vec V.! 0)) >> return vec
  evalChunk i = rpar (rdeepseq (vec V.! i)) >> evalChunk (i-1)
```

Things to learn from this solution:

1. It uses the `Eval` monad, which is strict so we're sure to spark everything (compared to wrapping things in `let` and remembering to use bang patterns).
2. Contrary to your proposed implementation it (a) doesn't construct a new vector, which is costly (b) `evalChunk` forces evaluation of each element using `rpar` and `rdeepseq` (I don't believe `rpar vec` forces any of the vector's elements).
3. Contrary to my belief, `slice` takes a start index and length, not a start and end index.  Oops!
4. We still need to import `Control.DeepSeq (NFData)`, but I've e-mailed the libraries list to try and fix that issue.

Performance seems similar to the first `parVector` solution in this answer, so I won't post numbers.

Comment: Note Tom's library is now on Hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-strategies

Answer (score 3):

1) As you probably know, `vector` is a product of the [DPH](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell) work that has proven harder than the researchers initially expected.

2) Unboxed vectors can't divide up the work for individual elements across multiple CPUs.

3) I'd be a lot more hopeful for boxed vectors.  Something like:

```
using (map (rnf . (vec !)) [0..V.length vec - 1]) (parList rdeepseq)
```

Or maybe you can avoid constructing the list and using parlist.  I think just assigning parts of the array is sufficient.  The below code is likely broken, but the concept of making your own `parVector` using `rnf` and dividing the vector in half until it is a single element (or some tunable chunk size of elements) should work.

```
parVector :: Strategy (Vector a)
parVector = let !_ = eval vec in Done vec
  where
  chunkSize = 1
  eval v
    | vLen == 0 = ()
    | vLen <= chunkSize = rnf (v ! 0) -- FIX this to handle chunks > 1
    | otherwise = eval (V.take half v) `par` eval (V.drop half v)
    where vLen = V.length v
          half = vLen `div` 2
```

Comment: Tom, thank you for the idea. I'll try it. Did I understood correctly that even this `parVector` won't work on unboxed vectors?

Comment: Right. Perhaps Roman (author of vector, posts here sometimes) will come in and make things clearer but unboxed data can't be a delayed computation (can't be a thunk).  Forcing any element of an unboxed vector forces the others and any parallelism must be done inside the Vector package (if that's even possible).

Comment: I tried `parVector` strategy, though I had to rewrite it to build with the newer `parallel` (see the edited question). Unfortunately, it didn't give any speed-up.