# How to write Haskell array strategies

Tags: arrays, haskell

I want to write a strategy to evaluate items in an array in parallel. The old strategies had `parArr` to do this ([see here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.3/html/libraries/parallel/src/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#parArr)). But this is not found in the new Control.Parallel.Strategies module.

E.g.
parallel list evaluation: `` map f myList `using` parList rdeepseq ``

I would want to be able to do something like: `` amap f myArr `using` parArr rdeepseq ``, where `amap` is from Data.Array.Base and applies a function to each of the elements (sequentially).

The following seems to work but I wonder if it is doing it right, and want to know how I could define my own `parArr`.

This works: `` amap ((+1) `using` rpar) $ Array.array (0,4) [(0,10),(1,20),(2,30),(3,40),(4,50)] ``

Comment: Are you sure that works? Because ``(+1) `using` rpar`` is quite strange. It will evaluate the expression `(+1)` in parallel, which does not make much sense because `(+1)` is a lambda-expression, thus it already is in a WHNF and there is nothing left to evaluate. You may have meant ``amap ((`using` rpar).(+1))``, no?

Comment: Why not use `repa` or `vector`, which already have parallel strategies, and are much more flexible in general?

Comment: @Rotsor: thanks for pointing that out. it makes sense what you said. +1

@Don Stewart: `repa` or `vector` are definitely more flexible but i'm trying to limit the changes to an existing codebase by just introducing parallelism using strategies. Using strategies, I can have a good separation between the algorithm and parallel behaviour. If it works, the next thing would be to look at your suggestion. thanks +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186902/how-to-write-parallel-code-with-haskell-vectors/4197275#4197275), I wrote a parallel evaluation strategy for the vector package.  That should be a good place to start.  You can [see the code on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-strategies/0.1/doc/html/src/Data-Vector-Strategies.html#parVector) in the [vector-strategies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-strategies) package.

I don't have time to give a full answer - perhaps I'll edit this later.  Feel free to comment with extra questions and direction.

Comment: This has given me a good idea about writing strategies. There is also a link to github which shows how to use `parTraversable` on plain arrays. In my case, this should give the behaviour that i expected.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from all the good advice given: The reason that there is no `parArr` anymore is simply that it has been replaced by the more general `parTraversable`. Just say:

```
amap f myArr `using` parTraversable rdeepseq
```

That should give you the behavior you asked for.

Comment: Thanks Peter, for making me realise that the `parTraversable` does just the job of what i would expect `parArr` to do. +1